# C++ arithmetic with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I am trying to add the following:

I have an array of double pointers call A. I have another array of double pointers call it B, and I have an unsigned int call it C.

So I want to do:

```
A[i] = B[i] - C;
```

how do I do it? I did:

```
A[i] = &B[i] - C;
```

I don't think I am doing this correctly.

Edit: What I want to do is, take the value at index i of the double pointer array and subtract an int from it, then store that result into a double pointer array at index i.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with doing A = B - C ? Subtracting pointers from different arrays makes no sense (and is undefined behavior)

Comment: Instead of saying "So I want to do: (code snippet that apparently doesn't do what you want it to)" you should explain what you want in English. We have no way of knowing what you intended that code snippet to do any more than your compiler.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a bit unclear, but if A and B are arrays of pointers to double and you want to change each pointer with a fixed amount of exactly C, then, for each element in A:

A[i] = B[i] - C;

should do it. &B[i] takes the address of the pointer itself, so it is a completely different thing.

sample code:

for(int i = 0; i < size_of_A; ++i)
A[i] = B[i] - C;

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't have a simple syntax for mapping, you either

(1) Use a loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1482; ++ i)
  A[i] = B[i] - C;
```

(2) Use `std::transform` in `<algorithm>`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
...
std::transform(B, B+1482, A, std::bind2nd(std::minus<double>(), C));
```

(There may be a Boost library to simplify this.)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

```
&( *B[i] - C )
```

But i think you cannot assign it directly to A[i]. First you have to create a temporary (T) array of double.

```
for(int i=0; i< size_of_B; i++){
  T[i] = *B[i] - C;
}
for(int i=0; i< size_of_T; i++){
  A[i] = &T[i];
}
```